# Traduction possible de ­­« soft-deletion »

Tags: anglais, choix-de-mot, informatique, terminologie

Je suis en train d'écrire un rapport à propos d'une base de données pour l'université et je me suis frotté à un terme technique que je ne saurais traduire.

Il s'agit du terme « soft-deletion » qui permet en base de données de conserver les données, mais de pouvoir les filtrer comme si elles étaient supprimées. Cela permet entre autre la restauration rapide des données et de pouvoir conserver un historique des entrées.

J'avais pensé à *suppression douce* ou encore à *suppression silencieuse*, mais j'aimerais avoir votre avis sur la question!

Comment: Est-ce que la *soft deletion* est une étape avant une **vraie** suppression?

Comment: @n.1 Pas vraiment, il n'y aura pas de "vraie" suppression sur ces tables là

Comment: Ok, j'aurais proposé la *corbeille* (comme sous Windows, etc.) si ça avait été le cas, c'est à dire un espace temporaire où les donnés sont mises de côté avant la restauration ou la suppression. L'*archivage* (réponse de Jimmy.D) me semble être l'expression la plus claire, même si ça n'est pas une traduction stricte.

Answer (score 4):

Ce n'est peut-être pas le terme académique, mais *suppression réversible* correspond à ce mode de gestion des données.

Cela correspond aussi à *suppression sans destruction*.

Answer (score 3):

Suivant la description donnée : « Cela permet entre autre la restauration rapide des données et de pouvoir conserver un historique des entrées. »

J'irais avec « archivage », un peu comme dans une boite de courriel où les messages archivés n'apparaissent plus, mais peuvent être restaurés rapidement.

Comment: Certes, _archivage_ n'a pas la connotation de suppression.

Answer (score 3):

Le synonyme anglophone *logical delete* et son antonyme *physical delete* se prêtent mieux à la traduction immédiate en français à mon avis.

Par conséquent, **dans un rapport académique**, j'utiliserais les expressions *suppression logique* et *suppression physique*.

Cependant, s'il s'agit d'une traduction de l'UI, je dirais plutôt *suppression* et *suppression définitive*.

**Note**: L'idée est venue de cette [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-soft-delete-of-database-record).

Answer (score 2):

Les termes *hard / soft* pour la qualification des operations de suppression dans une base de données ne sont pas les plus claires deja en anglais. Ils expriment l'idée de réversibilité, ou permanence de l'operation. *silencieuse* n'est pas du tout une bonne traduction a mon avis. Tu peux choisir

- suppression **reversible / irreversible**
- suppression **simulée / réelle**
- suppression **relative / absolue**
- suppression **abstraite / concrète**